# Component based android application

Tags: android

This might not be a direct programming-related question, rather an architectural based question. The challenge I'm facing is to split my android application in several piece so it's highly configurable. I want to do this do deal with different customers demands, notice that this application should not be released in Google Play. Today my application has some components that will be sort of standard and not configurable components. Examples of these components are [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) with the [Slidemenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). The illustration beneath hopefully gives you the idea

[image]

Note: `Workflow 2` and `Workflow 3` has total different logic and layouts.

Some of my logic are already dealt with, I have a method for sending different transaction. The type of transaction can be my `email` or a `webservice`

The way I handle this is by implementing an `interface`:

```
public interface ISender {
    public abstract int send(Context c, String attachmentPath, String identifier); 
}
```

I have a class `SenderFactory` with a method of the type `ISender` which will return an `ISender` object:

```
public static ISender createSender(Context context) throws InvalidWorkflowException   {

  if(WorkflowChooser.GetWorkflow().equals("mail")) 
      return new MailSender();
  else if(WorkflowChooser.GetWorkflow().equals("webservice")) 
      return new WebserviceSender();
  else
    throw new InvalidWorkflowException("The Application doesn't support this way of transfering cases"); 

}
```

This method is called from my `CreateTransaction` class

```
    public int createTransaction(String pcn, String fileName) throws MailException {

        try
        {
            ISender s = SenderFactory.createSender(context);
            sent = s.send(context, fileName, pcn); 
        } 
        catch(InvalidWorkflowException e) {
            _log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return sent;
    }
}
```

This way, my application will decide which type of transaction to used based on a `xml-file` which is included in my build.

As you might have figured out, if you read this long post, I want to apply this to my whole project, not only to the logic, but also the `UI`, to make it more component-based. I wonder what is best practice, is there any recommended ways of doing this? Does anybody have any examples of previous projects?

Comment: Time to use [module based DI](http://square.github.com/dagger/).

Comment: Did you have any success on this?

Comment: @joaquin I haven't tried yet, but I've used Autofac and other IoC containers for such use. Take a look at IoC